How to receive file send from flask with curl?
Here the server side code with python & flask:
from flask import Flask, request, send_file
import io
import zipfile
import bitstring

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/s/',  methods=['POST'])
def return_files_tut():
    try:
        f = io.BytesIO()
        f.write("abcd".encode())
        return send_file(f, attachment_filename='a.ret.zip')
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Bellowing is curl command:
λ curl -X POST  http://localhost:5000/s/ -o ret.tmp
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     4    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 4 bytes remaining to read

How should I use curl to receive the file?

This is working fine for me.

@user459872 tried on windows & macos, the error still present

it's not an "error", have a look at the content of the buffer before sending it with print(f.read())

When data is written, the pointer moves to the next position in the file. This means that before the data is read to make it available as a download, the pointer points to the end and no further data is read. So the download fails. In order to offer the file as a download, the pointer within the file must be reset to the beginning using seek(0).
The attachment_filename attribute of send_file() is now deprecated and has been replaced by download_name.
@app.post('/s/')
def return_files_tut():
    f = io.BytesIO()
    f.write("abcd".encode())
    f.seek(0)
    return send_file(f, download_name='a.ret.zip')


alternatively, pass directly the whole string to the BytesIO-constructor, see example
